# GIS developer blogs ... recommendations?

Tags: open-source-gis, references, arcgis-platform

I'm looking for recommendations for GIS blogs ... specifically GIS *developer* blogs. I'm less interested in the geography than in how apps are put together.

I'd like to keep up with ESRI ArcGIS as well as open source tools.

Which blogs are you fine people reading?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Few from my side, mostly out of ESRI world:

- [CARTODB](http://blog.cartodb.com/)
- [MapBox](http://developmentseed.org/blog/mapbox/)
- [OPENGEO](http://blog.opengeo.org/)
- [Linfiniti Geo Blog](http://linfiniti.com/)
- [Smathermather's Weblog](http://smathermather.wordpress.com/)
- [GISTUTOR](http://www.gistutor.com/)
- [Open Source Computing and GIS in the UK](http://www.archaeogeek.com/)
- [Google Geo Developers](http://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.ch/)

Answer (score 8):

Here are some GIS developer blogs (python included):

[Another GIS Blog](http://anothergisblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)

[ArcGIS & Python](http://arcgisandpython.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)

[Dave Bouwman](http://blog.davebouwman.com/feed/)

[Café Python](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/feed/)

[CGarrad](http://blog.cgarrard.com/feeds/posts/default)

[Dll Shepherd.Net](http://www.dllshepherd.net/feeds/posts/default)

[GIS Solved](http://gissolved.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)

[Guerilla GIS](http://www.redtrails.com/blog/?feed=rss2)

[Nerd tips for things you probably won't use](http://justinberke.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default)

[Node Dangles](http://nodedangles.wordpress.com/feed/)

Comment: I think the last link to Orama's Blog is incorrect?

Comment: true, the blog seems to have been closed.  Removed from the list and my Google reader!

Answer (score 2):

To read relevant Open Source GIS blogs in an integrated way, visit http://planet.osgeo.org/

It aggregates more than 120 blogs, among them many developers' blogs (Tip: use j/k keys to navigate easily).

Answer (score 1):

Not always GIS/Map related, but still interesting nonetheless. It's written by a few developers at the New York Times and focuses more on design and prototyping of interactive maps and graphics, and not necessarily GIS applications. Seeing their processes has been really helpful to me. They also use R a lot for spatial stuff, which is cool.

[Chartsnthings](http://chartsnthings.tumblr.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This guy has some great stuff on the ESRI Javascript API. Not sure what kind of development you're doing, but if it's JS, this is a must read!

http://odoe.net/blog/